# Error when getting git LFS files: Object does not exist on the server: [404] Object does not exist on the server

Tags: git, github, git-lfs

I downloaded and installed Git Large File Storage. Now I'm trying to get lfs files from the existing repository in github (not mine).
I tried:

`git lfs clone https://github.com/xxx/xxx`

then in my local just cloned repo:

`git lfs fetch --all`

`git lfs pull`

I also tried the same but without "lfs".

The repository is cloned but for all lfs files always this error is shown:

```
[301582dabd8c6ac7bdf626c7e4a1d64c8f9665b65b6334b44642bdfb78054575] Object does not exist on the server: [404] Object does not exist on the server
```

and then:

```
error: failed to fetch some objects from 'https://github.com/xxx/xxx.git/info/lfs'
```

As a result, instead of real large files, their small pointers that can be seen in GitHub itself are cloned.

At the same time this command:

`git log --all -p -S 301582dabd8c6ac7bdf626c7e4a1d64c8f9665b65b6334b44642bdfb78054575`

gives the following results:

```
commit 36c7dba69de90d99f0c305fce13a598b8f06b443
Author: xxx
Date:   Wed Sep 11 18:01:25 2019 +0200 
Add embeddings 
diff --git a/embeddings/wikipedia/0.pkl b/embeddings/wikipedia/0.pkl
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..5ee94da
--- /dev/null
+++ b/embeddings/wikipedia/0.pkl
@@ -0,0 +1,3 @@
+version https://git-lfs.github.com/spec/v1
+oid sha256:301582dabd8c6ac7bdf626c7e4a1d64c8f9665b65b6334b44642bdfb78054575
+size 588838774
```

I am not very confident user of GitHub, especially, of LFS. So, the question is: am I doing something wrong or does it indeed mean that the files do not exist on the server?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This error message is an HTTP 404 Not Found error.  Essentially, that means that Git LFS tried to pull down the file, but it wasn't there.  In all likelihood, the user did not upload it properly, possibly because they didn't run `git lfs install`.  If they had run that command, the `pre-push` hook installed in their repository would have pushed the files to the server before the Git objects were uploaded.

Since the files weren't uploaded, there's no way for you to download them.  You'll have to ask the author to run `git lfs push --all` in their repository to upload them to the proper location so they can be downloaded.

Comment: Is it possible to force git to skip this file? In my case, the "author" no longer works for the company. I don't need that specific lfs file, but I need the rest of the pull to succeed

Answer (score 16):

If you are migrating from one GIT repo to another, you'll need to fetch the full LFS history from the source repo and push the full LFS history to a new (empty) target repo to avoid missing lfs objs.  My steps to migrate from source repo to target repo:

Clone from source repo and download full LFS history

```
git clone http://source... local_src
cd local_src
git lfs fetch --all
```

Push to new target repo and upload full LFS history

```
git remote set-url origin https://target...
git push --mirror origin
git lfs push origin --all
```

Comment: is this pushes only lfs files or the entire project? How do i push the entire project?

Comment: I'm trying to migrate from bitbucket to github. There's one file in bitbucket lfs. It's the one file that is throwing this 404 error, including when I use `git lfs fetch --all`. Not sure why this is happening.

Comment: Update: I ended up having to download the file from bitbucket manually using https://bitbucket.org/REPOURL/admin/lfs/file-management/ and copying it to the git's `lfs\objects\XX\YY\` dir corresponding to this file name's first 4 characters. Not sure why git wasn't able to download it automatically from bitbucket and was resulting in a 404.