# I am stuck in a side-branch because git can't find lfs object

Tags: git, git-branch, git-lfs

I did a `git checkout side-branch`. After a bit, I tried to go back `git checkout master` which failed with error:

```
Updating files: 100% (712/712), done.
Downloading code/external/CNN-WordSim-main/assets/corpus.pkl (17 KB)
Error downloading object: code/external/CNN-WordSim-main/assets/corpus.pkl (5f722ca): Smudge error: Error downloading code/external/CNN-WordSim-main/assets/corpus.pkl (5f722cae5ff766982b32729971bbab91f1ba61f0c61d2b08868cd358a778c903): [5f722cae5ff766982b32729971bbab91f1ba61f0c61d2b08868cd358a778c903] Object does not exist on the server: [404] Object does not exist on the server
```

Apparently the file corpus.pkl cannot be found anymore. I have also tried `git checkout --force master` with the same result. The point is that *I don't care about corpus.pkl*, it's an old file from a different repo I clone/forked/downloaded some time ago and I don't really care about it anymore. I am happy to lose the whole CNN-WordSim-main repo, I just want to go back to `master`.
I am at complete lost. Any idea?

Comment: [related, but not the answer you're looking for](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62852772/1256452)

Comment: Meanwhile, from a Git point of view, you can always tell Git not to bother using the smudge filter for that particular file (or at all). Make a clone without using `git lfs clone` and you'll get a repository where *no* LFS handling is done; use this to fix up the commit.