# Error while creating Branch in VS Code post cloning in VS Code and error during Cloning in VS Code repo

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, azure-devops, git-lfs

When I am cloning a repository from DevOps to VS Code [ver 1.71.0] I am getting:

1. VS Code error stating:

```
[ "Git:remote:Azure Repos" ]
Below is error during cloning repo frm Devops in VScode-
Downloading web/__image_snapshots__/FlatrisGame-FlatrisGame-snap.png (32 KB)
Error downloading object: web/__image_snapshots__/FlatrisGame-FlatrisGame-snap.png (7980b8e): Smudge error: Error downloading web/__image_snapshots__/FlatrisGame-FlatrisGame-snap.png (7980b8eaaa00e44c5d48503f90718ddb72ff095a922a50448783c9b89737ca98): [7980b8eaaa00e44c5d48503f90718ddb72ff095a922a50448783c9b89737ca98] LFS object not found: [404] LFS object not found

Errors logged to 'C:\Devops\flatrisVB\.git\lfs\logs\20221108T071419.4210913.log'.
Use `git lfs logs last` to view the log.
error: external filter 'git-lfs filter-process' failed
fatal: web/__image_snapshots__/FlatrisGame-FlatrisGame-snap.png: smudge filter lfs failed
warning: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed.
You can inspect what was checked out with 'git status'
and retry with 'git restore --source=HEAD :/'
```

2. As it clones and restores all file on local folder which I then add in Visual Studio Code.
3. When I now try to use CTRL+Shift+P and give git create branch command on Repo and try specify New Branch name I get following error which fails to create new Branch ["Git: The Following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout" ]  and it fails to create new branch
4. Would appreciate if any one has experienced same problem and how do we resolve this. I am using Azure VM win 2022 server. I have installed Git and configured Name and email-id .NodeJs is also installed.

I was expecting no error during cloning Repo from Azure Devops in VSCode.

Also I am not able to create New Branch for imported repo.

I tried to re-import different Repo's from GitHub to Devops and then in VS Code but ended with same 2 problems mentioned above.

Comment: This might be it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62852772/error-when-getting-git-lfs-files-object-does-not-exist-on-the-server-404-obj

Answer (score 0):

[Solution for Query No 3]With my trial and error i was able to figure out resolution for problem where i was not able to create new branch from "master" in VSCode post cloning Repo from DevOps.

i am not sure whether we need to do this but this is what works in VS code . I found out that post cloning Repo in VSCode if we do "commit" and then try to create new Branch it works and allows me to create new branch and work...
I know we normally do commit post we update any changes in Branch ..but this workflow resolved my issues as i created multiple branches did some test changes..did commit and publish that new branch back to DevOps and created Pull request ...all works fine...
So this is resolution that worked for point 3 query mentioned above ..

I am still working to resolve Query no 1 where i get error during Cloning Repo from DevOps..